# Grails portlets on liferay

Tags: java, grails, liferay, grails-controller

I'm a Grails developer and I started development on Liferay 2 months ago.
I believe that if I can use Grails on Liferay I will increase my productivity by 2.
So here is my questions : 
- What plugins to use to develop Liferay portlets ? I used some grails plugins but I got an error when generating portlet.xml.
- How can I configure the Grails dispatcher to work with Liferay. For example : to dispatch urls like this /web/guest/test?myportletId_WAR_aname_action=/user/show/1&myportletId_WAR_aname_windowstate=exclusive... to usercontroller and invoke show action ?
- How to get actionRequest, ActionResponse when invoking the action ?

Regards

Comment: Nobody has an answer? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you consider the portlet as a particular view into your app it should definitely be possible. You could do it using a simple spec Java portlet that pulls information out of your main project, or look at the current [Spring MVC Portlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/portlet.html) and [Groovy Portlet](http://www.liferay.com/web/alberto.montero/blog/-/blogs/866130) to see if those could be shortcuts for your implementation. I have worked with both (albeit not in the context of a Grails project) and can happily report that they work well with stock Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure that you can't create a portlet using Grails. You can of course write portlets in Groovy using GORM for data access. GSP isn't currently available outside of Grails so you might have to live with JSP for the views.

I've found that using the portlet support in spring MVC makes your life a little bit easier than raw portlets.

Good luck

Comment: I have tried a Grails portlet on Liferay but all the requests are dispatching to only one controller. It means that Grails need a specific dispatcher to understand liferay urls. Grails is based on spring MVC I think it could be very easy to implement it as spring mvc can run under liferay

Comment: good work. Is there anything you can release in the open? Trouble with portlets is that they are only losely related normal webapps, the spring portlet MVC stack is almost mirror of the normal spring MVC stack, could be possible.

Comment: There is a Grails plugin for liferay developement but it's buggy I couldn't generate the associated portlet.xml file. I'll see if there is a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Look for discussion of com.liferay.util.bridges.wai.WAIPortlet . I've taken little Grails apps that I've built, dropped them in the hot deploy directory on a generic Liferay 6.06 install as an experiment, and presto, they show up as portlets! I guess Liferay cooks up generic portlet.xml etc. for them. They aren't beautiful, nor are they tied into Liferay's Services API or database, but they run as a portlet, and of course you can also find them where they should be as stand-alone webapps. Fun!

Comment: The problem is that with a grails portlet installed that way you can only have home page displayed because grails can't get to know request parameters as they are consumed by Liferay. There is a missing peace of cake and I guess it's the Liferay dispatcher for grails apps (in order the understand requests).

Comment: Um, no. I just did it with a little webapp I wrote. I can log in to it, show the data, edit the data. The only real problems I can see is that the authentication and database are completely separate from Liferay, and the whole grails page gets rendered so there's an extra header in there. Other than that, seems to work fine.